# How to find out the HP P2000 SAN storage usage

Tags: hp, storage-area-network

I have a HP P2000 SAN using for multiple purposes. I need to see the entire SAN storage usage, like free space, used space, raw space...

So far all I can get is the raw space and volume size from web console, there is no option for used space and free space for each volume or for entire SAN storage.

I could not find any command for showing such information.

Anyone knows anything about it?

Comment: Assuming you want something like file system usage, there's no way for the P2000 to know what any write operation to any LUN is *for*.  The LUNs exported from such storage are presented as "Here's some storage. It's this big. What you with with it and what the bytes you put on it mean are all your responsibility."

Answer (score 1):

To show information about disks:

```
show disks
[disks]|[free]|[all]|[vdisk vdisk]
[perf]
```

To show information about all disk slots:

```
show disks encl
```

To shop information for all or specified vdisks and see used/free capacity execute command

```
show vdisks 
[vdisks]
[perf]
```

Check the source for more commands: https://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=4118559&docId=emr_na-c02520779&docLocale=en_US

Comment: Non of those commands gives you the usage of disks / vdisks or volumes. they can tell you the size of the disks or volumes and I/O etc, but no usage information like %free or %used.

Comment: `show disks` command shows info about physical disk so you have the total capacity. `show vdisk` command shows vdisk size and free space.
Is there any chance you could share out of those commands? I have no HP SAN available at the time to show my output.